# JavaScript function doesn't recognize my HTML element

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my JavaScript function, in the "for" part it doesn't recognize the HTML elements when I use `i` to refer to the list position, but when I use `[0]` or `[1]`, for example, it *does* recognize it. So there must be a problem with the loop part but I can't figure out what is it, here is the code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    window.animacion_click_menu = function (id) {
        var i;
        var menu = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('LI');
        var bloqueActual = document.getElementById(id);
        for (i = 0; i <= menu.length; i++) {      //recorre los LI devolviendolos a su posicion original
            menu[i].style.marginLeft = -40;
            menu[i].style.opacity = 1;
        }
        bloqueActual.style.marginLeft = 200;
        bloqueActual.style.opacity = 0;
    };
})();
```

and here's my html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mario Luque Marchena</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1 class="titulo">Bienvenid@</h1>
    </center>
    <div id="main-screen">
        <ul id="menu">
            <center>
                <li id="sobremi" onclick="window.animacion_click_menu('sobremi');">Sobre mi</li>
                <li id="portafolios" onclick="animacion_click_menu('portafolios');">Portafolios</li>
                <li id="animacion" onclick="animacion_click_menu('animacion');">Animacion</li>
                <li id="back-end" style="border-bottom-style: dashed;" onclick="animacion_click_menu('back-end');">Back-End</li>
            </center>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animaciones.js"></script>
</body>
```

if you have any suggestions to make the code better, are welcome too, i'm learning to code. thank you!, and sorry for the bad english in case it was

Comment: You want to use `i < menu.length`, not `<=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is really on the for loop.
Take a look on:

```
for (i = 0; i <= menu.length; i++) {
```

it should be:

```
for (i = 0; i <= menu.length-1; i++) {
```

Otherwise, it will try to iterate from 0 to 5 while your menu array has only 4 items.
The result is that in the last iteration, when you try to access the element menu with the inexistent index (menu[5]) you get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

Other possibility to overcome this is to change <= to < and work with the loop as:

```
for (i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Yes that was the error i had! it was such a simple error hahaha i changed the <= for < and it worked! thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

use window.onload() or

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  //Put your code here
})
```

I think your code is getting executed before DOM creation.

Comment: The error was in the loop, i solved it, but what you're saying could happen too, i will use one of those, thank you!

Comment: `$('document').ready(function(){...})` is equivalent to `$(function(){...})`, for those who are not aware.